# How to pass the updated model values back to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I would like to create a MVC form for editing user data.

In the controller I have created the following methods:

```
public ActionResult UserEdit(DemoRes.Models.User user)
{
   checkSignIn();
   return View("User", user);
}

public ActionResult UserSave(DemoRes.Models.User user)
{
   checkSignIn();
   MongoDBManager dal = new MongoDBManager();
   dal.EditUser(user);
   return RedirectToAction("UserManagement");
}
```

In the form "User Management" a user is selected from the list and passed to UserEdit in controller. The form "User" then appears with filled user data - so the data is successfully passed from controller to view. In the view I would like to enable a user to either update the data or just "cancel" the action and go back to list of users.

In order to do so I have created the following User.cshtml form:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "User";
}    
<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#btnCancel").click(function(){
            window.location.href = url;
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("UserSave", "Admin")",
                type: "POST",
                data: data
            });
            window.location.href = url;
            return false;
        });
    });

    function SubmitFrm(){
        var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
        window.location = $("#RedirectTo").val();
    }

</script>
@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("UserManagement", "Admin"));
<h2>User</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" data-bind="value:username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" data-bind="value:email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" data-bind="value:password">
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="isActive" data-bind="checked:isActive">Is active</label>
                </div>
        @if (ViewBag.Owners != null)
    {

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="prop">Owners:</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                    @foreach (DemoRes.Entities.Owner o in ViewBag.Owners)
                {
                    <option value=@o.Id.ToString()>@o.FirstName @o.LastName</option>
                }
                </select>
            </div>
    }
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" name="addEditUser" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" name="addEditUser" id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var data=@(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
        function viewModel() {
            this.username=ko.observable(data.Username);
            this.password=ko.observable(data.Password);
            this.email=ko.observable(data.Email);
            this.isActive=ko.observable(data.IsActive);
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();
```

When the user hits the "Save" button, the following function is called:

```
$(function(){
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("UserSave", "Admin")",
                type: "POST",
                data: <modified data>
            });
            window.location.href = url;
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Here, I don't know what is the correct way to pass the modified data back to UserSave method in the controller. I would be very thankful if anyone suggested the way to bind the data correctly.

Comment: type: "POST", data: { UserName: $("#username").val(), Password: ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the view-model to JSON string using the `ko.toJSON()` method:

```
var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body);

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UserSave", "Admin")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ko.toJSON(vm),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    });
```

(The main benefit of `ko.toJSON` method is its ability to automatically handle observables)

However, since the actual function that posts the data to the server is not part of the view-model, I had to call `ko.dataFor` in order to get the bound view-model (which is not ideal).

If you'll make the action part of the view-model, it'll look better:

```
function viewModel()
{
    this.username=ko.observable(data.Username);
    this.password=ko.observable(data.Password);
    this.email=ko.observable(data.Email);
    this.isActive=ko.observable(data.IsActive);

    this.submit = function(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UserSave", "Admin")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            });
    }    
};
```

Then change the button HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click: submit"
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-default"
        value="Submit"
        name="addEditUser"
        id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)